# Partition powerpoint lines into different objects

Tags: powerpoint

I have many power point slides and each slide has many lines but all those lines are in the same objects. I want now to add some animation including appears for each line with click.

How I can partition the lines in each slide such that every line will be in its own object

Note, I am using powerpoint 2010

Thanks,

AA

Answer (score -1):

This isn't perfect; you'll need to add more code to pick up ALL of the formatting from the original text, but it's a start. Click within the text box you want to modify, then run the TEST sub.  Once it's adjusted to your taste, it's a fairly simple matter to extend it to act on every text box in the entire presentation (though not tables, charts, smartart, stuff like that)

```
Sub Test()
    TextBoxToLines ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
End Sub


Sub TextBoxToLines(oSh As Shape)

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oNewShape As Shape
    Dim oRng As TextRange
    Dim x As Long

    With oSh
    Set oSl = .Parent
    With .TextFrame.TextRange
        For x = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
            Set oRng = .Paragraphs(x)
            Set oNewShape = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                oRng.BoundLeft, oRng.BoundTop, oRng.BoundWidth, oRng.BoundHeight)
            With oNewShape
                .TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeNone
                .Left = oRng.BoundLeft
                .Top = oRng.BoundTop
                .Width = oSh.Width
                .Height = oSh.Height
                With .TextFrame.TextRange
                    .Text = oRng.Text
                    .Font.Name = oRng.Font.Name
                    .Font.Size = oRng.Font.Size
                    ' etc ... pick up any other font formatting you need
                    ' from oRng, which represents the current paragraph of
                    ' the original text
                    ' Bullets, tabs, etc.
                End With
            End With
        Next
    End With
    End With

    oSh.Delete

End Sub
```